# pip requiring "--break-system-packages" after update to 23.10

Tags: package-management, python

After I updated from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 23.10, `pip install foobar` warns about "externally-managed-environment" and requires me to add `--break-system-packages`.

Is this expected after the update? Is there a way to disable this warning?

Note that I explicitly want the version of the packages coming from pip, and not the version from Ubuntu packages (I need specific versions for development).

Comment: We can close as dupicate of this one. Do you know why this happens? Is the new version of pip causing this behavior?

Comment: This one is a better duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3
```
 add following lines to ~/.config/pip/pip.conf:
[global]
break-system-packages = true
```

Comment: Both Python and Pip changed: https://lwn.net/Articles/867657/ https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/